# Magento - How to set footer to 100% width?

Tags: css, magento, footer

I would like to know how can i set my footer width to 100%? I tried to set .footer-container and .footer width to 100% as well as absolute position.

Here's the website:

http://buysmartcardsonline.com/

Comment: Your footer is set to 100% of it's parent container. Also, you should provide your own code, not a link to your site. Do you want it to be 100% of the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hubro mentioned in his answer moving the `div.footer-container` outside the `div.page container` would be ideal. But if you don't want to move the divs you could try using absolute positioning for the footer like below

```
.wrapper{
   position: relative;
}

.footer-container{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -27px; (height of the footer container)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you moved your `div.footer-container` outside the `div.page` container, it should automatically cover the width of the page.

Before:

```
<div class="page">
    ...

    <div class="footer-container">...</div>
</div>
```

After:

```
<div class="page">
    ...
</div>
<div class="footer-container">...</div>
```

Comment: On which Magento file do I do that? page.xml? Thank you :)

Comment: @ActiveCard: I don't know anything about Magento in particular, but look for which ever file/template contains the tags in my answer, edit it and save it. Should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `class="footer-container"` from `class="page"` and make it direct child of `class="wrapper"`

from

[image]

to

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following code - I hope this is what you are looking for

```
.footer-container {
                   left: 0px;
                   width: 100%;
                   position: fixed;
                   bottom: 0px;
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the .footer-container outside the .page and then inside the add a div within the .footer-container with the class of .page to get content within the footer the same width.

```
<div class="page">Your page content</div>

<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="page">
       Footer Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do I do that? On Magento page.xml ? Thank yoou :)

Comment: Wherever your footer is located on your website.